# what if i copy-paste "Can freewheel of coaster brake be used in combination with derailleur?" to this se?

Tags: support, on-topic, specific-question

see https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/85544/can-freewheel-of-coaster-brake-be-used-in-combination-with-derailleur Can freewheel of coaster brake be used in combination with derailleur?

is that question on topic in engineering se? can i copy-paste it there?

Comment: A relevant FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/335251)

Answer (score 2):

If there is a specific engineering topic that came from your question, then that could be a question here. Stack Exchange does not like the same question to be posted on multiple sites. Your question is on-topic at bicycles, so it should stay there.

As the comments have said on your question, there is a lot there. If the answer that you received did not help you, then think about how you could focus another question on the very specific question that you have. This question could be asked at either site depending on the topic.

Bottom line: Don't copy and re-post the question.

Comment: if i did not post it there, just posted it here, as it is, would it be ok for this site?

Comment: It would've had similar issues with being focused on a single question. Also, the Bicycles site probably had a better idea of what was being discussed the first time without as much explanation needed about specific bike terms.

Comment: the discussion under the question is about old version of it. i wanted to make new questions and leave this to be automatically closed. but i created only 1 more question, more is not allowed due to low quality of existing questions. i have written a new question, but could not only submit it.  so i put it in place of that very first one as a complete rewrite.